# Batch script (logoff/shutdown) to clear Chrome Cache folder for all users

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently using this:

```
@echo off
set ChromeDir=C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
del /q /s /f "%ChromeDir%"
```

This works well, however only for the current logged on user.  Looking to use this as a logoff/shutdown GPO or scheduled task but we'd like it to clear down this folder for ALL USERS.

My question is what is the variable for that where I've got `%username%` - if there is one at all.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: depends, how Chrome was installed. There is the `%public%` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `%USERPROFILE% variable to build up the path to the cache.

```
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@set _CachePathRelativeToUser_=AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
@set _Users_=!USERPROFILE:%USERNAME%=!
@for /d %%d in (%_Users_%\*) do @rd /s /q "%%d\%_CachePathRelativeToUser_%
```

Note that users can move their profile data, so this won't find them all, just those that share a common root. While moving user profiles to a drive other than `SYSTEMDRIVE` is not a common practice, it is done. It is far less common however, to find user profile data that isn't under a common root.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: My user of leading and trailing underscores in variable names is just my convention for naming variables that I expect to have script run-time lifetimes.  When I test, I check for any variables starting with an underscore to verify I haven't left any trash hanging around in the environment.